# Issue with join in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created a simple ADF pipeline that has two sources (S1, S2) and stores data from these sources into Azure Cosmos DB sink using **left outer join** (condition: s1.abc = S2.abc). After running this pipeline, I can see all columns from S1 and none of the columns from S2. Why is that? Please help me understand.

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see all columns from S1 and none of the columns from S2

Since you mentioned left outer join in your question, so i think you are using Data Flow Activity to transfer the data.  I tested on my side an it works for me.

Firstly,please check the statement of left outer join in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join):

[image]

Then please refer to my sample test:

I have 2 csv files as below:

[image]

[image]

My data flow activity as below, the B is the join key:

[image]

Output in cosmos db,the row from left stream has no match,so the output from right stream is NULL:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should be careful about the schema of the dataset. when you create it "import schema" must be selected correctly. your problem might be about that as well. here how i solved a similar problem:

i was processing some csv files and did select the schema as none. because of this, the key in join conditions did not appeared there. after i change it to "from connection/store", join flow executed correctly and the data were visible in preview tab.

[image]